# Array manipulation/mapping returning undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to reorganise/restructure my data to send back to the api. I am mapping values into their respective new properties.

Incoming prop:

```
const data = [
  {
    otherProperty: "string",
    otherPropertyTwo: "string",
    personId: "1269",
    peopleGroups: [
      { group: "SENIORS", groupStatus: "paid" },
      { group: "Infants", groupStatus: "not_paid" }
    ]
  }
];
```

and need to restructure into this whilst not leaving in any other properties other than the ones below:

```
 const statusArrayUpdate = [{
     "personid": "1269",
     "groups": [
       {
         "group": "seniors",
         "status": "paid"
       },
    {
         "group": "Infants",
         "status": "not_paid"
       }
     ]
   }]
```

I tried this but getting undefined on the 2nd mapping, groups property...

```
const statusArrayUpdate = data.map(d => ({ ...d, personId: d.personId, groups: d.peopleGroups.map(s => [group: s.group, status: s.groupStatus]) }));
```

Comment: Can you fix `data` so it's a valid JS object?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` on your `data` array and just take the `personId` and rename the `peopleGroups` of each object, and rename `groupStatus` to `status` for each element in `groups`.

```js
const data = [
  {
    otherProperty: "string",
    otherPropertyTwo: "string",
    personId: "1269",
    peopleGroups: [
      { group: "SENIORS", groupStatus: "paid" },
      { group: "Infants", groupStatus: "not_paid" }
    ]
  }
];

const statusArrayUpdate = data.map(({ personId, peopleGroups }) => ({
  personId,
  groups: peopleGroups.map(({ group, groupStatus }) => ({
    group,
    status: groupStatus
  }))
}));

console.log(statusArrayUpdate)
```